# с# Прерывание выполнение функции не дожидаясь ее результатов, как?

Tags: c#, threading

Есть основной поток, сейчас в нем через System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); выполняется функция по таймауту

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitTimer_func();
}

public static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer_tick_func;
public void InitTimer_func()
{
    timer_tick_func = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer_tick_func.Tick += new EventHandler(timerEvent_func);
    timer_tick_func.Interval = 100; // in miliseconds
    
}

private void timerEvent_func(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    function_name();
}


private void function_name()
{
    ...
}
```

Как возможно сделать прерывание выполнения функции function_name не дожидаясь результата ее выполнения? Пробовал timer_tick_func.Stop() и timer_tick_func.Dispose() они дают завершиться функции. Возможно мне нужно применить другой метод?
Смысл в чем, в основном потоке я делаю проверку, по типу, читается ли память в процессе, и если нет, то нужно прервать function_name не дожидаясь, иначе программа закрывается с ошибкой.
Возможно как вариант обработать исключение вызванное из основного потока, но как его передать в этот таймер? Или все же придется переписать под Thread или нечто иное?

Comment: Ну можно переменную какую-нибудь снаружи выставить, если у вас там внутри цикл, например, и проверять эту переменную в цикле. А если прямо прервать вообще в любом месте исполнение, то наверное да, это только через тред. Ну или наверное лучше тогда через `Task` и `CancellationTokenSource`

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Comment: Проблема как раз и заключается в том, что ошибка в 90% возникает во время выполнения цикла (времязатратный), по типу:
память читается? да
делаю функцию
,
,
память не читается <----------- тут нужно сделать прерывание
. ошибка

Comment: Так может, нужно обернуть вызов `function_name();` в `try-catch`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov попытка выполнения задач в function_name к процессу, где память не может быть прочтена, вешает процесс, наша программа конечно же продолжит работать, но процесс, с которым происходит взаимодействие уже помрет

Comment: Но вообще как-то странно это выглядит насчёт "память не читается". Что за память? И нельзя ли это проверять там же, где выполняется функция, чтобы не городить огород с передачей информации между потоками? Или это не `managed` код, какие-то `dll`-ки на `C++`? Но тогда вопрос несколько вообще про другое на мой взгляд.

Comment: @CrazyElf получается что в теле функции function_name перед каждым шагом, нужно проверять переменную в которую передается состояние памяти из основного потока? Думал что будет проще прервать второй поток, если переменная в первом примет нам неугодное состояние. Без dll, прямое чтение. Смысл в том, что читается состояние процесса, в котором мы проводим взаимодействие, но вовремя проведения этого взаимодействие (оно длительное), состояние может поменяться. Смысл в отлавливании иззменения состояния и прекращении выполнения взаимодействия с ним

Comment: Ну, я всё-равно так и не понял, что за память. И почему нельзя во втором потоке сделать ту же самую проверку, что вы делаете в первом, если их состояние всё-равно как-то зависит между собой. Ну короче если не хотите разбираться и переделывать архитектуру, то почитайте по ссылке выше которую Александр привёл и используйте `CancellationTokenSource`, как я и сказал - и будет именно то, что вы хотите. Если мы оба вас правильно поняли.

Comment: Попробую, вернусь с результатами

Comment: Как там ваши результаты? Интересно же )